# How to open external url using WKWEBVIEW

Tags: swift

I have an app which for example the domain is hello.example.com, but when the user click on a link which is example.com/example it has to open it as external link. I am using swift 5 and WKwebview

I have this code, but I need that when the url contains hello, the url opens in the webview otherwise open safari, but it doesn't work. I am looking for url contains something like that but i did not find something useful for my case.

I have this code , but obviously does not do what I need.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
            if url.host != "example.com" {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                return
            }
        }

        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

Comment: Look at `url.path`.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track.

Replace `if url.host != "example.com"` with `if url.path.contains(…)` and it should work.

Using `url.path.contains(…)` we can check the existence of a given string.

```swift
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
            let trigger = "example" // or "hello"
            if url.path.contains(trigger) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                return
            }
        }

        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

Comment: @JairoCarvajal Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Please read the guide on accepting an answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)